# schtasks command has an unclear error

Tags: powershell, scheduled-task

I am trying to change the expiry date of an Scheduled task using powershell because  there are more than 40 tasks for users of same thing.
`schtasks.exe /Change /tn "Cache USer" /u "mydomain\administrator" /p <password>  /ed 23/07/2019`
but I get an error and translation or searches did not help.

```
FEHLER: Ungültige Syntax. Der Benutzername kann nicht ohne den Systemnamen angegeben werden. Geben Sie "SCHTASKS /?" ein,um die Syntax anzuzeigen.
```

translation is something like

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. The user name cannot be changed without the system names can be specified. Enter "SCHTASKS /?
```

to display the syntax.

What is the problem it does not work evn if I use "/s" switch.

So server is a Windows 2012 R2 Terminal Server. DC is another system in the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cmdlets for Scheduled Task in Powershell.

To set an expiry date you would need to use the EndBoundary property under Scheduled Task Triggers.

[Powershell - Scheduled Tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=win10-ps)

[Scheduled Task expire and delete using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337135/powershell-v4-create-remote-task-scheduler-task-set-to-expire-and-delete)